# Correlation between multiple variables of a data frame Group by a different variable

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, correlation

Assuming I have a data frame like the below (actual data frame has million observations). I am trying to look for correlation between signal column and other net returns columns group by various values of signal_up column.

I have tried “dplyr” library and combination of functions “group_by” and “summarize”. However, I am only able to get correlation between two columns and not the multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>%   
   group_by(Signal_Up) %>%   
   summarize (COR=cor(signal, Net_return_at_t_plus1))
```

Data and desired result are given below.

**Data**

[image]

**Desired Result**

Correlation between "signal" Vs ["Net_return_at_t_plus1", "Net_return_at_t_plus5", "Net_return_at_t_plus10"]

Group by "Signal_Up"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use `summarise_at` to perform the correlation over several columns.

Here, I took the `iris` dataset as example:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Length), ~cor(Petal.Width,.))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1 setosa            0.278       0.233        0.332
2 versicolor        0.546       0.664        0.787
3 virginica         0.281       0.538        0.322
```

For your dataset, you should try something like:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Signal_Up) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Net_return_at_t_plus1:Net_return_at_t_plus1), ~cor(signal,.))
```

Does it answer your question ?

---

NB: It is easier for people to try to solve your issue if you are providing reproducible example that they can easily copy/paste instead of adding it as an image (see: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: Thanks very much @dc37 for the solution. It works perfectly fine. I will provide reproducible example instead of the image next time. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Thanks @dc37, its done. Just want to ask whether it’s possible to create the categories/ groups on the fly for the variable "signal"? 

Currently, I had to create a variable "Signal_Up" (by round up values from "signal" variable) in order to categorize the main variable "signal" (categories: -4, -3, … , 3, 4, 5,..). 

Something like - Groupby "signal" by [A, B, C]  WHERE 

A = signal >  1 ,
B = -1 > signal > 1,
C = signal < -1.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not really clear. And without a reproducible example, it will be hard to address your issue

Comment: Thanks, I will post that as a separate question altogether.